# Updating knockout variables/properties calculation isn't working?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I've grabbed bits of a jsfiddle that did a paging example.  I have this at the top of my page:

```
var persons = []; //holds array of names/tables

var viewModel = {
    fields: ko.observableArray(persons),
    pageSize: ko.observable(1),
    pageIndex: ko.observable(0),
}; 

viewModel.pagedRows = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var size = this.pageSize();
    var start = this.pageIndex() * size;
    return this.fields.slice(start, start + size);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return Math.ceil(this.fields().length / this.pageSize()) - 1;
}, viewModel);
```

I then have a jquery ajax call to read a plain text file and that sets the property of viewModel.pageSize to a value (10 in my example) and that works fine.  The data call that returns an object array updates viewModel.fields and the first 10 rows are displayed on screen.

I have a "window.setinterval" that calls a "paging" function every 10 seconds that pages through the data:

```
function paging() {
    viewModel.pageIndex(viewModel.pageIndex() + 1);

    if (viewModel.pageIndex() > viewModel.maxPageIndex) {
        viewModel.pageIndex(0);}
}
```

It almost works...  the pageIndex keeps incrementing and the data on the page refreshes and shows the correct starting point in the "pagedRows" subset of fields that is bound with knockout. However, as soon as the first timed "paging" function is called, "pagedRows" suddenly leaps from containing 10 objects to all the remaining objects in the "fields" observablearray.  I don't understand why?  The first time through it correctly sets it to 10, then when it does the slice to get the next 10, it does so but seems to append all the remaining objects after the 10 it has fetched. It's like the "number of items to fetch" in the pagedRows function in the viewmodel goes wrong.

I have no doubt it will be a simple misunderstanding on my behalf but I'm stumped now. Been looking at this all day and my beginner skills can't sort it out.

Also the comparison to "maxPageIndex" to trigger a return to zero fails to work and it just keeps incrementing forever!

Answer (score 0):

viewModel.maxPageIndex is a dependentObservable.  That means it's this big fancy object.  So you can't just refer to

```
viewModel.maxPageIndex
```

and expect to get the calculated value back.  Rather, call

```
viewModel.maxPageIndex.peek()
```

to get the calculated value back.

Please note that they are no longer called dependentObservables, but have been changed to computed observables.

For more information, see the documentation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I've added the answer below.

Comment: -1, both statementes are incorrect. `peek()` should not be used for general access, only for access under the special case that you don't want computation to occur. Second, the name change is optional, `dependantObservable` still maps to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of problems.

Firstly I was using the old fashioned "dependentObservable" instead of "computed" but that wasn't the problem as it still works that way!

Secondly I missed off the parentheses at the end of "pageMaxIndex" in my paging method:

```
if (viewModel.pageIndex() > viewModel.maxPageIndex()) {
```

now works and doesn't need "peek" to return the value.

The slice issue was because my json call was returning a string value for page size. This when added to the offset was causing the result to be a concatenated string instead of a numeric result.  I was ending up with "1020" instead of "30"!

Thanks for the pointers from CodeThug